# Passing bearer token IIB 10 in HTTP Request Node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I Need to pass bearer token to make an API call But I can not find much details
using IIB v10. Not sure if IIB v10 Supports to Send Bearers Token in HTTP Request Node.

```
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Authorization" = 'Bearer ' || _oauthToken;
```

Should work in IIB v10?
Could you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes This Worked for me as the following :

```
DECLARE _oauthToken CHARACTER 'tokenData';
        
SET OutputRoot.HTTPRequestHeader."Authorization" = 'Bearer ' || _oauthToken;
```

My service once the token passed through request header and it's valid one , my expected data returned as i tired with postman .